# Dynamic actions based on field input in Django

Tags: django, dynamic, django-forms, wms

Im trying to make a Django site, but after lots of research and tutorials i still cant find the answer to this. In GUI toolkits there is often an option to perform some action (eg validity checking) as a user is typing charachers into a field or any other type of event.

Is there equivalent event-action functionality in Django web interfaces and how?

Specifically i would like a user to be able to write a WMS url in a field, and as this is being typed or upon clicking a button have a preexisting geodjango map widget in the same screen be updated to show that wms and possibly zoom to its extents. Will this have to reload the entire html page with updated html code or could it be done without any reloading?

Another example would be if a user chooses a country from a choicefield to zoom the map to the selected country (assuming we can find the extent).

Comment: You will need to write Javascript for this; that is not a limitation of Django but just how the web works.

Answer (score 0):

As @daniel-roseman says, what you're really looking for is a JavaScript solution, as it's not really a Django problem.

You could create a view within Django that spits out HTML for an AJAX request, but you may find it simpler to just use jQuery, hooking into the `change` event of the input (or better still, hook into the `keydown` event of the input).

A caveat to using the `keydown` event is that you should attach your callback to a timer, as your callback runs before the full text of the input control has been read (ie: if your user types "appl", then hits the final "e", the last `keydown` event will only give you the value "appl" unless you attach it to a timer... it's a little hacky but it works).

You might consider reposting this as a JavaScript or jQuery question where you'll probably get more helpful responses. I could go into more detail but without knowing your comfort level with JavaScript, I don't know if I'd be teaching you to suck eggs :)